# Use sed without the need to write on file

Tags: shell, redirect, sed, command, sh

I'm looking for a way to bypass the read write on file.
Is it possible to directly use sed on results of a command?
`#!/bin/sh` is used, as I used NetBSD, `sed -i` is not working so I have to use `sed -e` then redirect results to a file.

results of command `disklabel xbd0`

```
netbsd# disklabel xbd0 >/file ;
# /dev/rxbd0d:
type: unknown
disk: xbd0
label: 
flags:
bytes/sector: 512
sectors/track: 2048
tracks/cylinder: 1
sectors/cylinder: 2048
cylinders: 1000
total sectors: 2048000
rpm: 3600
interleave: 1
trackskew: 0
cylinderskew: 0
headswitch: 0           # microseconds
track-to-track seek: 0  # microseconds
drivedata: 0 

16 partitions:
#        size    offset     fstype [fsize bsize cpg/sgs]
 a:   2048000         0     4.2BSD   1024  8192     0  # (Cyl.      0 -    999)
 c:   2048000         0     unused      0     0        # (Cyl.      0 -    999)
 d:   2048000         0     unused      0     0        # (Cyl.      0 -    999)


netbsd# disklabel xbd0 | sed -e "s/match1/replace/" \
-e "s/match2/replace/" \
-e "s/match3/replace/" /file > /file.1 ;
```

how to send the results inside another command?

```
$ new_command -add $(results)
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect result of command
"disklabel xbd0 | sed -e "s/match1/replace/" \
-e "s/match2/replace/" \
-e "s/match3/replace/" /file" to /file.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already successfully piping the result of `disklabel` to `sed`.  So why don't you just pipe the results of `sed` to whatever new_command is?

```
disklabel xbd0 | sed -e "s/match/replace/" | new_command
```

For example, pipe the output of sed to `sort` and then pipe the output of that to `grep`.

Comment: yes it will : just add the arguments (if you know them in all cases and they do not depend on disklabel or sed's output) : `disklabel xbd0 | sed -e "s/match/replace/" | new_command  arg1 arg2`   (piping sends whatever the result of sed will be to new_command's STDIN. Nothing to do with the arguments of new_command)

Comment: @Stillakid Sure it will. You mean it needs a file argument? That’s what `/dev/stdin` is for.

Comment: @OlivierDulac yep, I agree, it'll send the output to STDIN

Answer (score 2):

> How to send the results inside another command? As `$ new_command -add $(results)`

If this is really what you mean, you can achieve this with the `xarg` command:

```
disklabel xbd0 | sed -e "s/match/replace/" | xargs new_command -add
```

Note that `xargs` will break your input at spaces, if you want juste one big argument, you can use `xargs -0`.

Most probably it is best to design `new_command` so that it takes its input from `stdin` and pass this input through a supplementary pipe.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're trying to redirect output of the commands to /file, you'll get "permission denied" , unless you're doing it as superuser.
For sending results of one command to another command, do this:

```
command2 `command1` #if command2 needs output of command1 as an argument
```

or

```
command2 $(command1)  #if command2 needs output of command1 as an argument
```